# Text Classification Using Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, text-classification, countvectorizer

I have list of words in text variable with their labels. I like to make a classifier that can predict the label of new input text.

I am thinking of using scikit-learn package in Python to use SVM model.

I realize that the text need to be corverted to vector form so I am trying TfidfVectorizer and CountVectorizer.

This is my code so far using TfidfVectorizer:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

label = ['organisasi','organisasi','organisasi','organisasi','organisasi','lokasi','lokasi','lokasi','lokasi','lokasi']
text = ['Partai Anamat Nasional','Persatuan Sepak Bola', 'Himpunan Mahasiswa','Organisasi Sosial','Masyarakat Peduli','Malioboro','Candi Borobudur','Taman Pintar','Museum Sejarah','Monumen Mandala']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
y = label

klasifikasi = svm.SVC()

klasifikasi = klasifikasi.fit(X,y) #training

test_text = ['Partai Perjuangan']
test_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_text)

prediksi = klasifikasi.predict([test_vector]) #test

print(prediksi)
```

I also try the CountVectorizer with same code above.
Both showing the same Error result:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: you ask how to solve a problem, but I cannot find anywhere in a question problem mentioned - so what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True)` instead?

Comment: @Coldspeed its showing an error: `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('<U22'),)`

Comment: @Drako the problem is the result showing an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` instead of the label (organisasi or lokasi)

Comment: CountVectorizer is already present in TfidfVectorizer, so no need to use both. Use either one or other at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to this line:

```
prediksi = klasifikasi.predict([test_vector])
```

Most scikit estimators require an array of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`. The `test_vector` output from TfidfVectorizer is already in that shape ready to use for estimators. You don't need to wrap it in square brackets (`[` and `]`). The wrapping makes it a list which is unsuitable.

Try using it like this:

```
prediksi = klasifikasi.predict(test_vector)
```

But even then you will gt error. Because of this line:

```
test_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_text)
```

Here you are fitting the vectorizer in a different way than what was learned by the `klasifikasi` estimator. `fit_transform()` is just a shortcut for calling `fit()` (learning the data) and then `transform()` it. For test data, always use `transform()` method, never `fit()` or `fit_transform()`

So the correct code will be:

```
test_vector = vectorizer.transform(test_text)
prediksi = klasifikasi.predict(test_vector)

#Output: array(['organisasi'],  dtype='|S10')
```